# How to take long string input with spaces in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    char input[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        cin.getline(input,sizeof(input));
        cout << input << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently having problem getting string input using getline but it seems to work only for short lines. Here is my input and output:

Input:

> 3 Can I have a large container of coffee right now Can I have a large
>   container of tea right now Now I wish I could recollect pi Eureka
>   cried the great inventor Christmas Pudding Christmas Pie Is the
>   problems very center

Output:

> Can I have a large container of coffee right now Can I have a large
>   container of tea right now

It doesn't store last line why?

Comment: Why you don't use ``string`` instead of ``char[]`` ?

Comment: What is T in your code?

Comment: T is the number of testcases

Comment: Read the documentation of `std:istream::getline`. It uses newline as delimiter. That is, once it encounters a newline, it stops reading.

Comment: Have your input contains any "Enter key" specially after the output's word?

Comment: I think @Nawaz is right.

Comment: for coding style and better readability, it is reocmmended not to use capital letters in variable names,....

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with this way, using `string` instead of `char []` :

```
int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    string input;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin,input);
        cout << input << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Check the code with the following test :

Input :

```
3 Can I have a large container of coffee right now Can I have a large container of tea right now Now I wish I could recollect pi Eureka cried the great inventor Christmas Pudding Christmas Pie Is the problems very center
```

Output:

```
3 Can I have a large container of coffee right now Can I have a large container of tea right now Now I wish I could recollect pi Eureka cried the great inventor Christmas Pudding Christmas Pie Is the problems very center
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the first input operator:

```
cin >> T;
```

This reads a number and stores it as an integer in T, but leaves the newline in the stream. Now the loop will read three lines, but the first will be an empty line.

You can fix this in several ways, the simplest is to just discard the newline after fetching the number:

```
cin >> T;
cin.getline(input, sizeof input);
```

A better way will be to check for end of file instead of fetching the number of lines in advance. And use `std::string` instead of char arrays as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
while(cin.getline(input,sizeof(input))){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    std::string temp;
    std::string input;
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        while(std::getline(std::cin,temp)) {
        input += temp;
    }
    std::cout << input << endl;
    return 0;
}
```